# Entity Framework does not map columns that are defined as Decimal

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a hard time understanding why Entity Framework skips columns that are defined as decimal. I've tried deleting the model a couple of times and adding it back using the database first approach but for some reason a few columns are not mapped.

The ones that are defined as `Date`, `Int` or `Text` have absolutely no problem. The ones that are giving me a hard time are the decimal ones and I have defined them as such:

- Name: Hours, Datatype: Decimal, Length/Set: 10,2, Unsigned: Checked, Allow Null: Unckecked, Zerofill: Unchecked, Default value: 0.00.

If I create a view with sums based on that same table, EF has no problem identifying the decimal columns. How can I add the missing columns to my model? What am I doing wrong and is there a workaround?

Thank you

Comment: if you tried to go to reference on your model, does it include the property?

Comment: Thank your the prompt reply Jeric. The property is not included. It's like the columns are not even in that table.

Comment: what version of EF are you using?

Comment: Version 6.0.0.0

Comment: Why can't you add them manually yourself? Also, what database are you using? I reckon you are generating the model from the database using VS, right?

Comment: Ricardo, I already tried that and I got an error, something about not being mapped. You are right. I finally found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending hours on this I finally figured it out. If you are facing the same problem make sure that your column are not **UNSIGNED**.

For some reason Entity Framework does not map decimal columns that are unsigned. Just uncheck that option and you should be good.